# How do I install the nvidia driver for my Nvidia GeForce 6150 LE on Ubuntu 12.04 LTS?

Tags: 12.04, nvidia

I have tried all the propriety drivers and my I still don't see that it's installed under the system settings/system/details. I get unknown under the graphics section.How can I fix this. Please help.

Comment: It doesn't really matter what it says under Details. Simply open the Additional Drivers utility and select the recommended driver, then click Activate.

Answer (score 0):

take a look here and I hope it works for you

http://www.upubuntu.com/2012/12/install-nvidia-driver-31309-beta-in.html

See! it's easy ;)